# How can i pass values from google cloud function (firebase) to front end?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently building an app with vuejs and firebase,to get new users in this app only admin privileged user can do this task. So with help of Admin sdk and cloud functions i managed to figure out how to trigger cloud function from the front end. The function it self does two things: 
1) Create user in authenticated section.
2) Add new user with userid as documentid in cloud firestore database. (/users/$(userid))

This part works great and all that. The only thing i'm missing now is for back-end to return userid for recently created user to front-end.

I tried achieving it by placing .then() after db.collection inside cloud functions code and by placing .then(result => inside front end of my code.

Cloud functions code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    displayName: data.name,
    password: '123456',
    emailVerified: true,
    disabled: false
  })
  .then(() => {
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
    .then(user => {
      db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        mail: user.email,
        name: user.displayName
      })
      .then(() => {
        return user.uid
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Front end code

```
methods: {
    addNewUser(){
      const createNewUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createNewUser');
      createNewUser({email: 'test@testing.com', name: 'testName'})
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
      })
    }
  }
```

in console i'm getting an array {data: null}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand Promises and Async functions.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Your code is like this using async/await.

Try the following code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email: data.email,
    displayName: data.name,
    password: "123456",
    emailVerified: true,
    disabled: false
  });
  await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({
      mail: user.email,
      name: user.displayName
    });

  return user.uid;
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm, i definitely need to learn more about async/await functions.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you sould try to use **cors** npm = https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors.

```
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
})

exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        //your process
        .then(user => {
            res.status(200).send(user.uid)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        })
    })
})
```